# Upgrade Visual Studio solution and project files programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a lot of visual studio projects which are delivered to the customer using installer. After the installation all project and solution files should be of the latest installed visual studio version. Is there any way to convert a lot of projects **fast**?

I've tried following:

1) parsing the files and replacing different properties like `ToolsVersion` etc. It's fast but not reliable and should be changed for every new Visual Studio which comes to the market (yearly from now AFAIK)

2) Using devenv upgrade feature, reliable but VERY slow:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyTmp", "*.sln", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToTheLatestVS;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/Upgrade \"" + file + "\"";
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

3) Tried to create a hidden instance of VS and manipulate solutions from there as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172383/open-a-vs-2005-solution-file-sln-into-memory), but no luck.

So is that possible to upgrade many project/solution files to a specific Visual Studio version in fast and reliable way?

Comment: You can use a combination of two options. Prepare project files for existing versions of Visual Studio in advance, and install the files already prepared. For future versions, you can use your second method.

Comment: @AlexButenko it's not an option as there are a lot of projects which are changing and we do support the customers from VS 2005, so we have to maintain 5 times as many project files. My second method is inacceptably slow.

Comment: Seems to me it should be an option as essentially all you are doing is dealing with a source control issue. You simply need to link the client install to some version of source control / production blob  and then pull the related solution and project files from there.

Comment: @rism I don't really understand how is source control coming into the game, could you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Let me present you a different view than the 2 you presented.
The fact that an upgrade is slow is that all kinds of checks are performed on the projects/solutions that you attempt to upgrade. An 'Upgrade Report' is generated to provide feedback on those checks. This is information that should not be ignored since it provides remedies on the mentioned issues.

You state that you deploy the projects/solutions via an installer. Presuming that you have a development team/tools that are up-to-date you could perform the upgrades as part of your installer design/development. Why would you not perform the upgrades yourself and include project files in your installer. During installation you would install the version of the project/solutions files that matches the target platform.

Comment: Yes, and do the conversion in your Continuous Integration script overnight. Of course you'll need a machine with all Studio versions installed, so it will be a bit of initial effort. This allows to review the upgrade reports e.g. every morning on company side before it fails on customer side.

Comment: As I written in the comment, we don't want to keep and maintain 5x more files than we already have. And every next year there will be one more because of new Visual Studio. Our projects are pretty simple (programming samples for our framework) and nothing can go wrong during the conversion so we don't need the upgrade report. The only thing I want to achieve is that the customer double clicks on the solution file and the sample is opened in the most modern VS installed.

Comment: You mentioned that the 2nd option was unacceptably slow. I have no idea on the number of projects vs the number of solutions but if you have 1 solution covering all projects and then just convert that 1 solution, is the performance then still unacceptable? If that is the case then you could just let the customer take the penalty of just-in-time upgrade when they actually open a project.